# Model instances without primary key value are unhashable with Djongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am getting the error `Model instances without primary key value are unhashable` when trying to remove a model instance from my admin panel.

**models.py**

```
from djongo import models
import uuid

PROPERTY_CLASSES = (
    ("p1", "Video Property"),
    ("p2", "Page Property"),
    ("trait", "Context Trait"),
    ("custom", "Custom Property")
)

EVENT_TYPES = (
    ("video", "Video Event"),
    ("track", "Track Event"),
    ("page", "Page Event")
)

class Device(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Platform(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    app_name_possibilities = models.TextField(blank=True)


class EventPlatformDevice(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = ""
    event_field = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applicable_apps = models.ManyToManyField('Platform', blank=True)
    applicable_devices = models.ManyToManyField('Device', blank=True)
    property_group = models.ManyToManyField('PropertyGroup', blank=True)
    custom_properties = models.ManyToManyField('Property', blank=True)
    

class Event(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=EVENT_TYPES)
    

class PropertyGroup(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    applicable_properties = models.ManyToManyField('Property')


class Property(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    property_class = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PROPERTY_CLASSES)
    format_example = models.TextField(blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

The issue lies with the `EventPlatformDevice` model I believe. The issue I think is when I create a new entry in the Admin panel and setup the relationships between `EventPlatformDevice.applicable_apps` it gets saved into the MongoDB using a `_id:ObjectId("61c25d36cdca07c8a6101044")` since that is what Mongo uses. I changed all of my primary keys to use a UUID since that was the only way I could get it to work. Now I think it is having a issue that some of my items are using `ObjectId` while some are using the `_id:Binary('7w6NaYCQQn6BS7jaOXUNZw==', 3)` that I am getting from uuid.

Is it possible to define what type the `_id` field is for everything? That way I can set it to use UUID.

Attached are images showing the data in Compass.

[image: first]
[image: second]

When I did not specify the `_id` in all my models, I was getting errors when deleting and accessing. It was like Django did not know how to reference the ObjectId. That is why I went with UUID. But since I cannot control the `dd.parsers_eventplatformdevice_applicable_apps` (2nd pic) it is having issues deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to define what type the _id field is for everything?

I am afraid not. *Each driver implementations may implement UUID serialization and deserialization logic differently, which may not be fully compatible with other drivers.* ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field)).

First, You can configure a UUID Representation, since PyMongo is using a legacy method to encode and decode UUID (0x03 subtype), you can change to cross-language compatible Binary 0x04 subtype. To do so in Djongo, just provide uuidRepresentation in the database settings as a standard ([docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/uuid.html#configuring-a-uuid-representation)):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'dd',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
            'uuidRepresentation': 'standard',
            'waitQueueTimeoutMS': 30000
        },
    },
}
```

Second, I would definitely try to make _id works. So the cration of the _id field will be provided by MongoDB server.
If that does not work for you:

```
_id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
```

then you could try this one:

```
_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, unique=True)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. 

models.py
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class ModernConnectUsers(models.Model):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)

settings.py
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'modernconnect',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
            'CLIENT':{'host': f'mongodb+srv://{mongodb_username}:{mongodb_password}@{mongodb_cluster}/?retryWrites=true','uuidRepresentation': 'standard','waitQueueTimeoutMS': 30000}}